# When using Landsat and Sentinel-2 data to implement the change detection, I got very different result

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, sentinel-2, change-detection

I used the code that is from gee-ccdc-tools.Now I know the actual time of change. I just change "getLandsat" to "getS2" for the change detection.And the result of change detection using Landsat data is right, the result of change detection using sentintl-2 data is wrong.They are about a year apart, like this:

[image]

The Landsat code：

```
// Define parameters
// Change detection parameters
var changeDetection = {
  breakpointBands: ['GREEN','RED','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2'],
  tmaskBands: ['GREEN','SWIR2'],
  minObservations: 6,
  chiSquareProbability: .99,
  minNumOfYearsScaler: 1.33,
  dateFormat: 1,
  lambda: 20/10000,
  maxIterations: 25000
}

var studyRegion = table2.geometry();

var params = {
  start: '2015-01-01',
  end: '2021-01-01',
  ChangeDetection: changeDetection,
  // Classification: classification,
  StudyRegion: studyRegion
}

// Filter by date and a location in Brazil
var filteredLandsat = utils.Inputs.getLandsat()
    .filterBounds(params.StudyRegion)
    .filterDate(params.start, params.end)
print(filteredLandsat.size())

params.ChangeDetection['collection'] = filteredLandsat
var results = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc(params.ChangeDetection)
print(results)

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: results,
  description: "CCDC_Landsat",
  assetId: "CCDC_Landsat",
  scale: 30,
  region: studyRegion,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

link of landsat: https://code.earthengine.google.com/b250c48be94b9e6cc824aca9e18dd1f6

The sentinel-2 code:

```
// Define parameters
// Change detection parameters
var changeDetection = {
  breakpointBands: ['GREEN','RED','NIR','SWIR1','SWIR2'],
  tmaskBands: ['GREEN','SWIR2'],
  minObservations: 6,
  chiSquareProbability: .99,
  minNumOfYearsScaler: 1.33,
  dateFormat: 1,
  lambda: 20/10000,
  maxIterations: 25000
};

var studyRegion = table2.geometry();

var params = {
  start: '2015-01-01',
  end: '2021-01-01',
  ChangeDetection: changeDetection,
  // Classification: classification,
  StudyRegion: studyRegion
};

// Filter by date and a location 
var filteredsentinel_2 = utils.Inputs.getS2()
    .filterBounds(params.StudyRegion)
    .filterDate(params.start, params.end)
    // .map(function(img){
    //   return img.addBands(img.normalizedDifference(['NIR','RED']).rename('NDVI'))})
    ;
print(filteredsentinel_2);

params.ChangeDetection['collection'] = filteredsentinel_2;
var results = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc(params.ChangeDetection);
print(results);

Export.image.toAsset({
  image: results,
  description: "CCDC_results",
  assetId: "CCDC_results",
  scale: 10,
  region: studyRegion,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

link of sentinel-2:  [enter link description here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/116ee8ab8d76d2dbab689a1fea24e5e6)

link of gee-ccdc-tools API:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?accept_repo=users/parevalo_bu/gee-ccdc-tools

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you believe something is wrong? You are looking at two different sensor systems so it is safe to assume that both the outputs will not be the same...

Comment: Have you contacted the author of the GEE code? Rather than  this community taking a guess at issues (other than obvious code issues) the original author of the code should have insight as to the differences, or perhaps even a coding error on their end.

Comment: thank you!I'll try.As soon as I get the results, I'll explain it here.